# How to show if date is invalid in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

This is what I tried so far but still nothing changed. I don't where to start to maybe someone professional can help me get through with this. This is for validation purposes.

**Code:**

```
$(function(){
var len = $('#groupContainer > div').length;
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i < len; i++){

    var number = $('#number_' + [i + 1]);
    var date = $('#date_' + [i + 1]);
    var count = i + 1;
    var message ="";
    console.log(number)

    var a = number.map(function(){
        return this.value;
    });

    var b = date.map(function(){
        return this.value;
    });

    var newObj = {number: a[0], date: b[0]}
    arr.push(newObj);

}

var messages={};
var message="";
for(var c = 0; c < arr.length; c++)
{        

    var groupMessage=false;
    for(var d in arr[c])
    {

        if(arr[c].hasOwnProperty(d))
        {      
            if(arr[c][d] == "")
            {
                if(messages[d]==undefined) {
                    messages[d]={groups:[]};
                }
                messages[d].groups.push(c+1);
            }

        }            
    }


}

var lastgroup=""

for(i in messages){
    m = messages[i];      
    var date = $('#date_' + i);
    console.log(date)
    if(m.groups.join(",")==lastgroup) {
        message = message.replace("Group "+m.groups.join(",")+" ","Group "+m.groups.join(",")+":\n");
        if(m == "Date" && date.length != 8)
        { message += i + ' is invalid!\n';
        }
        message+=i+" is required!\n";

    }else {
        message+="Group "+m.groups.join(",")+" "+i+" is required!\n";
    }
    lastgroup = m.groups.join(",");
}
if(message)
{
    alert(message);
}
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/z4yfohao/19/)**

If all field is not filled show:

```
   Group 1, 2 Number is required!
   Group 1, 2 Date is required!
```

Valid date must be `mm/dd/yy`

And if date is not really a date:

```
  Group 1, 2 Date is invalid.
```

And if one of the inputs is invalid.

```
  Group 2 Date is invalid.
```

If all field is filled do nothing.

Comment: You did not explained how you plan to validate Dates.

Comment: I think you could set up a smaller but well-defined problem similar to what you just posted. And then you'd solve it much easier. The code above is just a mess for any person who didn't know enough about your task.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend categorize objects by class, example:
.txtNumber for Number
.txtDate for date

You can use regExpAllow for keypress event and regexpMatch for the submit validation.

KeyPress Validation

```
$(document).on('keyup','.txtDate', function() {
    var regExpAllow = new RegExp('[^0-9/]', 'g');
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regExpAllow,''));
});

$(document).on('keyup','.txtNumber', function() {
    var regExpAllow = new RegExp('[^0-9.]', 'g');
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regExpAllow,''));
});
```

Submit Validation

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSubmit', function() {
    var regExpMatch = new RegExp('^[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[1-2][0-9]{3}$');
    $('.txtDate').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().match(regExpMatch) != null) {
            alert('Valid Date:'+$(this).val());
        } else {
            alert('Invalid Date:'+$(this).val());
        }
    });

    regExpMatch = new RegExp('^[0-9].[0-9]{3}$');
    $('.txtNumber').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().match(regExpMatch) != null) {
            alert('Valid Number:'+$(this).val());
        } else {
            alert('Invalid Number:'+$(this).val());
        }
    });       
});
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/BernardoBJ/o5dbnt51/4/

With this you can validate that characters can be entered and how it will be your final result (You can also validate the same way the regular expression of numbers if you want).

Implements this logic in your code.

note: gets a value that properly validate dates and your numbers format.

Answer (score 0):

All that mapping and looping is hard to follow...just loop through the elements once and deal with each type within the loop

```
function validate(){
     var errors = false,
         $cont = $('#groupContainer');
     // remove prior errors
     $cont.find('.error').remove();
     // loop over inputs
     $cont.find(':input').each(function () {
        // use id to sort out type
        var type = this.id.split('_')[0],
            value = this.value,
            msg = null;

        if (!value) {
            msg = 'This is required';
        } else if (type === 'date') {
            if (/****   your invalid date  method ***/ ) {
                msg = 'Invalid Date';
            }
        } else if (type === 'number') {
            if (isNaN(+value)) {
                msg = 'Not a number';
            }
        }
        if (msg) {
            errors = true;
            $(this).after('<span class="error">' + msg + '</span>')
        }   

    });        
    return !errors;        
}

alert( validate() ? 'Form is valid' :'Oooops! Not valid');
```

It's up to you to do date validation as no format was given

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rh02ngye/)**</kbd>